# Why forEach works on nodeList but not on collection

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Before ES6 the `forEach`method worked neither on `nodeList` nor on `collection`. But from ES6 the `forEach` method works on `nodeList`. But in case of collection still first we have to convert into an array and then we use forEach on that array.

My question is that why it is like that in ES6 `forEach` method was added to `nodeList` but was not added to `collection`? Is there any concept behind this which i am unaware of ?

Comment: [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) is kind of a relict. It's not updated for historical reasons, that makes a collection more backwards combatible. There's a lot old stuff in the DOM, which is badly outdated, but not removed, because of "historical reasons".

Answer (score 2):

The definition of HTMLCollection in the [DOM specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlcollection) published by WHATWG, notes:

> HTMLCollection is a historical artifact we cannot rid the web of. While developers are of course welcome to keep using it, new API standard designers ought not to use it (use `sequence<T>` in IDL instead).

This explains why evolutive API extensions are not applied to this interface.

This is not so much a decision in the domain of ES6, as the interface with the DOM is not covered by the EcmaScript specification, but by the [DOM standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) and [Web IDL](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/).

### Alternatives

Since `Array.from` and `for...of` have been introduced in EcmaScript, you can achieve a very similar thing as what `forEach` would do, and which works for both node lists and collections. For example:

```js
let elems = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

Array.from(elems, (elem, i) => {
    console.log(i, elem.textContent);
});

for (let elem of elems) {
    console.log(elem.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
```

Just like `forEach`, `Array.from` accepts an optional `thisArg` argument, and the callback gets both the element and its index passed as arguments. However, the callback does not receive a reference to the collection as third argument, like you would get with `forEach`. Also, `Array.from` returns an array, like `.map` would do on an array.

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave some feed-back?